# Actualizar un Cursor SQL Android

Tags: sql

Quiero Actualizar los datos del list view en el cursor sql que ingresa los datos alos objetos o elementos

```
    private ArrayList<Items> GetArrayItems() {
        ArrayList<Items> listitems = new ArrayList<>();

        //Cargando Registros de la Base de Datos
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "administracion", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor fila = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select codigo, imgproducto, fechabodega, producto, cantidad, precio, inversion, msgestado, msginventario, chekvalidar, cantidadproducto from articulos", null);
        if (fila.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                    listitems.add(new Items(R.drawable.img01, fila.getString(3), fila.getString(5), fila.getInt(10), fila.getString(0)));
            } while (fila.moveToNext());
        }
        //DeclaraArrayBotones(fila.getCount());

        BaseDeDatos.close();
        return listitems;
    }
```

Como ven yo ingreso nuevos datos pero necesito actualizar el cursor para mostrar los datos editados sin salir del activity

Aquí el Adaptador Personalizado

```
public  class  AdaptadorItems extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Items> listItems;
    private int TamañoArregloChek;
    private int NumeroRepetidor;
    private int PosicionEntero;

    public AdaptadorItems(Context context, ArrayList<Items> listItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    //cuenta los objetos que se van a cargar
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    //devolver la lista
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    //
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    //donde se va a crear la lista y asignaremos los valores de cada elemento
    // el final permite recoger la posicion de los elementos con position:
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        Items items = (Items) getItem(position);

        //se activa una ves y llama ala funcion para declra el arreglo con datos = 0 el if detecta la primera posicion para ejecurase una vez
        //public View getView enlista los elementos uno por uno nota!
        if(position == 0){
            TamañoArregloChek = getCount();
            //agregando 1 espacio mas para comenzar desde la fila 1 en el arreglo y dejar el 0 sin uso
            TamañoArregloChek = TamañoArregloChek + 1;
            ArregloDatos();
        }

        //el convertiView extrae todos los elemntos del layout activity_mostrar_listado
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_mostrar_listado, null);

        //creamos un OnclickListener en el convertview para que al seleccionar un elemento de la lista haga acciones
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // mostramos el mensaje en el context (contex,
                Toast.makeText(context, "Seleccionado" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        //casteamos y le damos datos alos elementos que hemos creado como objeto, los elementos restantes que no son como objeto no reciben ningun dato
        ImageView img_avatar = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_avatar);
        TextView txt_producto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_producto);
        TextView txtMostrarPrecio = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMostrarPrecio);
        TextView txtCodigoProducto = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCodigoProducto);
        TextView txtCantidadProductos = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCantidadElementosP);
        final CheckBox chkValidarOrden = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chekValidarOrden);
        Button btnMas = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMas);
        Button btnMenos = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMenos);

        img_avatar.setImageResource(items.getAvatar());
        txt_producto.setText(items.getProducto());
        txtMostrarPrecio.setText(items.getPrecioProducto());
        txtCodigoProducto.setText(items.getCodigoProducto());
        txtCantidadProductos.setText(String.valueOf(items.getCantidadProductos()));

        //creamos un cliklistener en el elemento solo en oncheked como Checkbox
        chkValidarOrden.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                    RecibirArreglo(position);
                }

        });

        //boton de mas cantidad producto individual
        btnMas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int PMas = position +1;
                int RecogerCantidad;

                AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(context, "administracion", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

                Cursor VerificarBTNMas = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select codigo, cantidadproducto from articulos", null);
                if(VerificarBTNMas.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        if(VerificarBTNMas.getInt(0) == PMas){
                            RecogerCantidad = VerificarBTNMas.getInt(1);
                            RecogerCantidad = RecogerCantidad + 1;

                            ContentValues BotonMas = new ContentValues();
                            BotonMas.put("cantidadproducto", RecogerCantidad);
                            BaseDeDatos.update("articulos", BotonMas,  "codigo="+PMas , null);
                        }

                    }while(VerificarBTNMas.moveToNext());
                }
                BaseDeDatos.close();


            }
        });

        //boton de menos cantidad producto individual
        btnMenos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int PMas = position +1;
                int RecogerCantidad;

                AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(context, "administracion", null, 1);
                SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos = admin.getWritableDatabase();

                Cursor VerificarBTNMas = BaseDeDatos.rawQuery("select codigo, cantidadproducto from articulos", null);
                if(VerificarBTNMas.moveToFirst()){
                    do{
                        if(VerificarBTNMas.getInt(0) == PMas){
                            RecogerCantidad = VerificarBTNMas.getInt(1);
                            RecogerCantidad = RecogerCantidad - 1;

                            ContentValues BotonMas = new ContentValues();
                            BotonMas.put("cantidadproducto", RecogerCantidad);
                            BaseDeDatos.update("articulos", BotonMas,  "codigo="+PMas , null);
                        }

                    }while(VerificarBTNMas.moveToNext());
                }
                BaseDeDatos.close();

            }
        });




        return convertView;
    }

    public void ArregloDatos(){

        OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked = new int[TamañoArregloChek];
        NumeroRepetidor = TamañoArregloChek -1;
        for(int S=0; S<=NumeroRepetidor; S++){
            OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked[S] = 0;
        }
    }

    public void RecibirArreglo(int A) {
        PosicionEntero = A;
        PosicionEntero = PosicionEntero + 1;

        //Toast.makeText(context, "" + PosicionEntero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked[PosicionEntero] == PosicionEntero ) {
            OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked[PosicionEntero] = 0;
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Arreglo Fila: "+ PosicionEntero+ " Eliminado " + OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked[PosicionEntero], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else {
            for (int L = 0; L <= TamañoArregloChek; L++) {
                if (L == PosicionEntero) {
                    OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked[L] = PosicionEntero;
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Arreglo: " + OrdenProducto.EnviarPosicion.ArregloPosicionCheked[L] +" "+ PosicionEntero, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

ahí en el adaptador hago el onclik porque en la activity donde llamo al adaptador no sirve el onclick

pero necesito actualizar mi cursor o el adaptador para volver a mostrar los datos que fueron editados y asi obtener lo que quiero y actualizar mis listview

Comment: Pon el código completo del adapter para ver como lo tienes montado

Comment: Vale vale lo hare

Comment: Lo que necesitas es añadir una función que haga un set del resultado del puntero a la variable listItems del adapter. Debes declarar una función en el adapter que realice esta lógica

Comment: pero como se hace xD soy novato enseñame  xD

Comment: tienes el código subido algún repositorio? no dispongo de mucho tiempo para generar el proyecto de 0.

Comment: Lo que quiero es que algiuen me explique que solución le puedo dar

Comment: el problemas es que todos sabemos que el codigo se ejecuta de arriba hacia abajo ahí todo bien. el cursor tiene un bucle que funciona solo una vez almenos que este dentro de una función asi podemos llamarla cuando queramos y ejecutarla de nuevo pero tira error de sintaxis en algunas partes al estar en una funcion

Comment: mi pregunta es como vuelvo a ejecutar el bucle o bien como ejecuto de nuevo el private ArrayList<Items> GetArrayItems()  porque solo se ejecuta una ves y no funciona metiéndolo en una función void

Comment: el adaptador solo es para el diseño de los componentes donde van a estar los datos, el private ArrayList<Items> GetArrayItems() hace que la información de la base e datos ingrese en los objetos del array list con un bucle donde toma la posocion de cada lista y introduce los datos de cada fila de la base de datos en las filas de los objetos ahora bien. alguien sabe como reinicio ese bucle del private ArrayList<Items> GetArrayItems() parta actualizar los datos editados de la base de datos?

Comment: Ya lo solucione graciasss mil gracias me has hecho llorar de felicidad  logre hacerlo posible gracias amigo eres mi héroe mas al rato publicare la solución para la mayoría que lo necesita mil gracias ahora puedo avanzar en mi proyecto